# What is the correct way to access controller that was required inside directive controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I have a directive with `require` property:

```
require: '^testBox'
```

now I want to get testBox controller inside controller of my directive. How should I do it?

I was trying to do so:

```
controller: function(){
  this.testBox.user
}
```

but looks like it does not work.
It's clear for me how to get required controller inside `link` function. But is there a way to get it inside controller without using `link`?

[Code on plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Sfk4ElyyYI64poQHQmUE?p=preview).

Comment: What are you tryng to achieve? Asking because it is very unusual to require controler of one directive inside another one. Usually you need data to be passed from one to another, but not the entire controller.

Comment: I'm experimenting with require controller possibilities. And for this task I want to reuse some methods from required controller

Comment: Set scope to true or comment it in user directive so that user directive will inherit from testBox directive.  Instead of ``this`` ,  use ``$scope`` to set value or function inside testBox directive , so those values or function will be available in User directive.

Comment: "Instead of this , use $scope" - I would like to have new "Controller as" style

Comment: "ControllerAs" is usefull when we need to user controller variables of functions inside template . see the last example @ https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is still an **[open issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5893)**. So at the moment you can not just inject the required controller into your directive controller. I have updated your [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rHCuqI473U1C8Wl3R0Sz?p=preview). It's definitely a bit hacky but the problem is; You cannot expose the `TextBoxCtrl` to the `UserCtrl` in either the `pre` or `post` link function because the controller gets executed first. So my idea is to use a `watcher` to observe a scope varibale called `textBox`. Once the value is defined I declare a variable on the `UserCtrl` and remove the `watcher`. Now you can simply use it in your template like so:

```
{{ user.textBox.name }}
```

Here is the code for the link function and the controller of the `user` directive:

```
link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, ctrl) {
  $scope.textBox = ctrl
},
controller: function($scope) {
  var vm = this;

  var watcher = $scope.$watch('textBox', function(newVal) {
    if(newVal) {
      vm.textBox = newVal;
      watcher();
    }
  });
}
```

However, you can also go with a link function instead. The required controller will be injected as the fourth parameter.

Comment: thank you for detailed answer and link to the issue!

Answer (score 0):

When you use controllerAs it's just added as a property of the underlying scope object (using the name you've defined).  Knowing this, you can attach the parent controller instance as a property of your child controller instance as follows:

```
    function exampleDirective() {
        return {            
            require: '^testBox',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, testBox) {
                scope.example.testBox = testBox;
            },
            controllerAs: 'example',
            controller: function() {
                // silly example, but you get the idea!
                this.user = this.testBox.user;
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: "scope.example.testBox = testBox;" - looks more like hack for me

Comment: Given the lack of official support I think that's what we're restricted to at the moment.  I know what you mean though, but this has been working well enough for me until something better comes along.